# Como sortear elementos (selecionar elementos aleatoriamente) de um vetor?

Tags: r

Como posso sortear elementos (selecionar elementos aleatoriamente) de um vetor no `R`? Por exemplo, quero sortear elementos deste vetor:

```
numeros = c(1,2,45,63,29,100,999,23.45,76.1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para sortear, por exemplo, dez valores do vector em causa de forma pseudo-aleatória, pode-se fazer o seguinte:

```
numeros <- c(1,2,45,63,29,100,999,23.45,76.1)
sample(numeros,size=10, replace=TRUE)
```

Nota: `replace=TRUE` para permitir repetições e `replace=FALSE` caso contrário.